# How do I make a reusable small layout for android where instances of this layout create a list item on a single page

Tags: java, android, class

I'm new to android development. I've bought a book and learned how to do most basic operations but I couldn't find out how to do exactly what I needed to make the app I'm working on right now.

Basically so far I have an add button on the main screen. This takes the user to a secondary activity with forms to fill in. What I need to figure out is how to get the user entered information (once the user clicks accept) to appear as a list item on the first page with a progress bar, title, remove button, etc. The user should be able to add as many of these items to the list as they want (each with their own individual remove buttons, titles, etc).

How would I generally go about doing this (what kind of classes should I use and such)? I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: read about gui fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think first of all you need in Activity A start for result (method available in Activity class) Activity B, where the user can fill the form and then return this as a data set to Activity A.

To display entries you in a dynamic list with you need to use ListView component with custom ListAdapter that allow you to add dynamically entries and than delete them.

Fist important thing is to read more about starting another activity for result and the secon to read more about ListView and custom list adapters.

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly the kind of direction I was looking for. I'm new to this site and apparently can't vote up your answer with a reputation below 15, otherwise I would!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist the data, use a SQLite database, possibly abstracted through a ContentProvider.

If persistence is not important, you could still use a ContentProvider, but use any suitable datastructure for storage e.g. an ArrayList that contains objects of a type that you define.

If abstraction and filling the list from a cursor through the ContentProvider is not important, you could share your data using a (public) static member. If you go down this road, remember to synchronize properly or else you will run in to problems.

It's really hard to help you when your question is really vague, and the answer above will still require you to read and learn a lot of concepts.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass from Activity A to Activity B you do by doing something like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Just put :

```
intent.put("value_id_for_activity_b", value);
```

before

```
context.startActivity(intent);
```

On Activity B you can retrieve it by doing :

```
String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("value_id_for_activity_b");
```

PS : there is a other type than String, and it will works if the "value" is a String.